# Standard "About" dialog in Qt

Tags: qt, dialog, designer

What's the standard way to implement an "About" application dialog in Qt? You know, the kind that pops up when you go Help > About... from the application menu.  I'm using Qt Designer to layout my main window, but I don't need anything fancy. It would be nice to do it in 2 lines of code instead of creating a new class or a new form in Qt Designer...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [QMessageBox::about](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#about) for simple about dialogs, or write your own QDialog subclass if you need anything more special/fancy.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a form. Right click on Project, Add New.., then select Qt in Files and Classes, select Qt Designer Form Class on right side and click choose..
2. Select Dialog without Buttons and click next.
3. Name it, for example "About".
4. Open About.ui in designer and change this window as desired, i.e. add icon, text, buttons (maybe only OK button) and save it.
5. In mainwindow.h add this object, i.e. `About *about;`
6. In mainwinodw.cpp instantiate it, `about = new About(this);` If you put `0` instead of `this`, it will not be a "modal" window, so add `this` in parentheses.
7. Go to Designer and in Action Editor right click on menu item and select Go to slot -> triggered.
8. Write `about->show();` in that slot.

Answer (score 3):

In my program Wallch ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/wall-changer/ ), i have added a new qt designer form class.

It works just fine!

( I referred the name of my application so if you want to check the project , not because it is my app )

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it with Python/PySide2:

First set up the menus/actions (I did this inside the `__init__` function of my [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QMainWindow.html) subclass):

```
menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&Help')

about_action = QAction('&About', self)
about_action.triggered.connect(self.about)
menu.addAction(about_action)
```

Then create a new slot to call [QMessageBox.about](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QMessageBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about):

```
@Slot()
def about(self):
    QMessageBox.about(self, 'title', 'text')
```